# Error when running nodejs app - cannot set property of undefined (load order?)

Tags: node.js, webpack, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to use Webpack to package my CSS & Javascript. I've installed Bootstrap 4.1.1, webpack 4.11.1, and jquery 3.3.1 with NPM. Node v10.3.0, and NPM 6.1.0

1. Node v10.3.0
2. NPM 6.1.0

I know the issue is bootstrap trying to use jQuery, and jQuery hasn't been loaded, but that's as far as I can get.

```
$$$1.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator;

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined
        at setTransitionEndSupport (D:\DevForm\DevForm\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:122:36)
```

App.js

```
..
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
..
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    },
    ...
        plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
};
```

Everything i've checked so far references an issue with an older version of bootstrap, a post from 2015 involving Bower, and documentation doesn't seem to acknowledge any issues like this.

I'm out of practice with Node, and completely new to webpack. How can I get it to load jQuery first, is that even my issue?

Comment: You should specify the Node and NPM versions as well.

Comment: Added Node & NPM versions to the question. Node v10.3.0
NPM 6.1.0

Comment: Hi @Spencel where you able to figure out a solution for this issue ?